# Springboot not closing http connections , the connections are in CLOSE_WAIT state

Tags: spring-boot

Most of the connections to the springboot application are in CLOSE_WAIT state , and are note being closed.

```
Tried configuration: 

server:
  servlet:
    session:
      timeout: 60s
```

Could anyone suggest a workaround